# How we dynamically wait for launching of word application using pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

I tried many ways to wait for word application to launch & stable. Then connect with the title name of launched application but none of them is working.
Steps:
1. launch word app
2. Then connect the word app with title name.
3. Then verify the ribbon text for Home menu

```
 app = Application(backend='uia').start(r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\WINWORD.exe')
    app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=5)  # wait until CPU usage is lower than 5%'''
    time.sleep(20)
    self.main = self.app.window(title_re='.* - Word')
```

currently, i am using static wait to avoid test failure but i want to handle it via dynamically.